# How to make dynamic cell in formula based on pointed value in excel spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have an issue with the cell range in formula and I don't know how to change it based on a predefined value in the spreadsheet. For example, from figure I have cells `B8:B12=0` (5 cells), however, if I want to change range to range `B10:B12=0` (3 cells) I should delete them from formula. How can I do the reference to a specific cell in a spreadsheet where I can simply change value 5 to 3 and it will change automatically, without interfering formula each time? I'm new to VBA, any help is appreciated.

[image: example]

Comment: I would start by looking at the OFFSET worksheet function. INDIRECT might also come in handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was mentioned before, you should try offset function and do something like:
AND(SUM(OFFSET(D13,-1,-2,-(G6),1))=0). Then the cells in the range B8:B12 would be possible to change inserting range in cell G6.

Comment: This is exactly what I was asking. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the =INDIRECT function to define your target cells, e.g.

```
=TEXT(INDIRECT(A1), "")
```

If I entered the text *B3* into cell A1, then this formula would return the *text value* in cell B3.

Let me know if it works for you.